# Как объявить упакованную структуру?

Tags: gcc, c, c++

При написании кода под Windows с использованием MS Visual C можно объявить упакованную структуру:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct _point {
    int x;
    int y;
    double time;
} point;
```

При этом выравнивание будет по байтам. Как сделать то же самое в gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя атрибут packed:

```
struct _point {
    int x;
    int y;
    double time;
} __attribute__((packed)) point;
```